# Problemas con Bootstrap DualListBox

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap

**Lo que tengo hasta ahora:** Muestro el contenido de un `JSON` en las opciones dentro de un select, el cual con la ayuda del plugin [bootstrap-duallistbox](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/) lo muestra en forma de un Dual List con el cual se pueden agregar o quitar ciertas opciones seleccionadas.

**Mi problema:** Lo que falla es que al seleccionar una opcion y pasarla a la siguiente area jala todas y no solo una, no se a que se deba, espero me puedan ayudar, les dejo el avance que llevo [AQUI](http://plnkr.co/edit/63ZRPOIiTr64yILOzUY7?p=preview)